# Phantom method?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I was getting the following error message while trying to debug my code:

```
Not able to submit breakpoint MethodBreakpoint [tarea11.Main].contarCapas '(Ljava/util/TreeSet<tarea11/punto>;)I', reason: Method 'contarCapas' with signature '(Ljava/util/TreeSet<tarea11/punto>;)I' does not exist in class tarea11.Main.
```

Now I realize that the contarCapas method ain't working at all, it's as if it isn't even declared.

Version 1:

```
package tarea11;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 *
 * @author darwin
 */

class punto{
    int x;
    int y;
    boolean usado;


    public punto(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.usado=false;

    }


    static double pendiente (punto p1, punto p2){
        double M = (p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x);
        return M;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object o1){

        if (o1 instanceof punto){

            punto p1 = (punto)o1;
            if (p1.x==this.x&& p1.y==this.y){

                return true;
            }
              return false;

        }

        else

            return false;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

       String string = this.x+" "+this.y;
       return string.hashCode();

    }

}

class PointComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){

        punto p1 = (punto)o1;
        punto p2 = (punto)o2;

        if (p1.y>p2.y){
            return 1;
        }
        if(p2.y > p1.y)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        else{

            if(p1.x>p2.x){
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }


    }

}

public class Main {


    static int contarCapas (TreeSet<punto> puntosOrdenados){

        int numeroDeCapas=0;

        HashSet <punto> puntosUsados = new HashSet<punto>();

        while (!puntosOrdenados.isEmpty()){

            punto p= puntosOrdenados.pollFirst();

            puntosUsados.add(p);

            //chequear contra todos los demas para hallar minArco
            double minArco=99999999;
            punto minPunto = new punto(-2001,-2001);
            double arco=0;
            for (punto siguiente: puntosOrdenados){

                if(siguiente.equals(p)){
                    continue;
                }

                arco=Math.atan2(p.y - siguiente.y, p.x - siguiente.x);
                if (arco< minArco){
                    minArco=arco;
                    minPunto = siguiente;
                }

            }

            if (puntosUsados.contains(minPunto)){

                numeroDeCapas= numeroDeCapas+1;

            }

        }

        return numeroDeCapas;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PointComparator pointComparator = new PointComparator();

        System.out.println(Math.atan2(-1.0, 1.0));
        //System.out.println(Math.acos(cont))
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        try{
        s = new Scanner(new File("entrada.txt"));
        } catch(IOException e){}
        int N,x,y;

        N = s.nextInt();

        while(N!=0){

            punto cebolla[] = new punto[N];

            TreeSet <punto> puntosOrdenados = new TreeSet <punto>(pointComparator);

            for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
                x=s.nextInt(); y=s.nextInt();
                cebolla[i]=new punto(x,y); //borrar?
                puntosOrdenados.add(new punto(x,y));
            }


           int cont= contarCapas(puntosOrdenados);
           System.out.println(cont);

             if(cont%2==0){
                System.out.println("NO");
             }else{
                System.out.println("SI");
             }
             N = s.nextInt();
        }
    }


    }
```

version 2:

```
package tarea11;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 *
 * @author darwin
 */

class punto{
    int x;
    int y;
    boolean usado;




    public punto(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.usado=false;

    }


    static double pendiente (punto p1, punto p2){
        double M = (p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x);
        return M;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object o1){

        if (o1 instanceof punto){

            punto p1 = (punto)o1;
            if (p1.x==this.x&& p1.y==this.y){

                return true;
            }
              return false;

        }

        else

            return false;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

       String string = this.x+" "+this.y;
       return string.hashCode();

    }

}

class PointComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){

        punto p1 = (punto)o1;
        punto p2 = (punto)o2;

        if (p1.y>p2.y){
            return 1;
        }
        if(p2.y > p1.y)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        else{

            if(p1.x>p2.x){
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }


    }

}

public class Main {


     int contarCapas (TreeSet<punto> puntosOrdenados){

         System.out.println("asdasdf");
        int numeroDeCapas=0;

        HashSet <punto> puntosUsados = new HashSet<punto>();

        while (!puntosOrdenados.isEmpty()){

            punto p= puntosOrdenados.pollFirst();

            puntosUsados.add(p);

            //chequear contra todos los demas para hallar minArco
            double minArco=99999999;
            punto minPunto = new punto(-2001,-2001);
            double arco=0;
            for (punto siguiente: puntosOrdenados){

                if(siguiente.equals(p)){
                    continue;
                }


                arco=Math.atan2(p.y - siguiente.y, p.x - siguiente.x);
                if (arco< minArco){
                    minArco=arco;
                    minPunto = siguiente;
                }

            }

            if (puntosUsados.contains(minPunto)){

                numeroDeCapas= numeroDeCapas+1;

            }

        }

        return numeroDeCapas;

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PointComparator pointComparator = new PointComparator();

        System.out.println(Math.atan2(-1.0, 1.0));
        //System.out.println(Math.acos(cont))
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        try{
        s = new Scanner(new File("entrada.txt"));
        } catch(IOException e){}
        int N,x,y;

        N = s.nextInt();

        while(N!=0){

            punto cebolla[] = new punto[N];

            TreeSet <punto> puntosOrdenados = new TreeSet <punto>(pointComparator);

            for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
                x=s.nextInt(); y=s.nextInt();
                cebolla[i]=new punto(x,y); //borrar?
                puntosOrdenados.add(new punto(x,y));
            }

           Main m = new Main();
           int cont= m.contarCapas(puntosOrdenados);
           System.out.println(cont);

             if(cont%2==0){
                System.out.println("NO");
             }else{
                System.out.println("SI");
             }
             N = s.nextInt();
        }
    }


    }
```

That gibbering `println` inside `contarCapas` isn't printing. The code isn't entering its call. Why?

Comment: you can try to start debugging at the starting of your main function.

Comment: You have made no effort to provide a [Short Self Contained Correct Example](http://pscode.org/sscce.html). Please reduce your question to the bare minimum.

Comment: @ tanyehzheng: Yeah, I tried debuggin from the main method and it works ok from there, it just doesn't acknowledge the call int cont= m.contarCapas(puntosOrdenados); It's as if it's not there.

Comment: what happened when you step into on that line? By the way, maybe you should try @Ryan solution.

Comment: hmm, should we add the tarea tag?

Comment: What is the meaning of Version 1 and Version 2? Are you just letting us guess? Or expecting us to do a text comparison to figure it out ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I'd expect to see if your source is out of sync with the bytecode that's running. Try a clean build of the code, or you could also use [javap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) to disassemble the bytecode and see if it looks like it matches the source, depending on your situation.

Comment: Yeah, I tried cleaning and re-building the code several times. Didn't work. I took it to another machine with the same version of Netbeans (6.9.1) and it did :-/

Comment: It worked on the new machine after 2 cleans and rebuilds, :-/